# Bearded dragon has weird discoloration

Tags: skin-condition, bearded-dragon

Recently I've noticed my dragon has some discoloration. It doesn't appear to be painful as he still curls his tail like normally when the area is touched.

I assumed it may be his lighting and heat, so recently he's been coming outside every morning to bask in actual sunlight and have gotten stronger bulbs for his tank.

He's not a climber so I don't believe it to be burns of any sort and his diet consists of gut-loaded insects (mainly cause he'd rather starve than eat some veggies) and I'm hoping it to just be his first shedding with me as I just recently got him.

Any ideas or information would be greatly appreciated.

[My Google album with dragon's photos.](https://photos.app.goo.gl/dGPdsMWJxNnsT12h1)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Junior is doing the same thing this is the first time I seen that weird color on him. He goes outside every morning and gives me attitude if I didn’t give him his spinach breakfast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What is Happening?

Your bearded dragon is shedding, it can take a week or two to fully get rid of the pieces.

### How Can I Help?

- Bathe him in luke-warm water
- Have rough textured materials for him to scratch on (i.e grass carpet or large rocks)

**Never** peel the shed, this hurts and can cause damage to the skin.

[image]

This is my bearded dragon, you can see the white patches on his legs and back - this is the old skin getting ready to come off.